# Can't connect to Tor with python 3.9

Tags: proxy, torsocks, python

I'm trying to access my tor server with python with the module torpy, but it didn'y worked. It continue sayying that the server is not reachable, but with tor I can connect with it.

I've tryied this code:

```
from torpy import TorClient

hostname = url
with TorClient() as tor:
    with tor.create_circuit(3) as circuit:
        with circuit.create_stream((hostname)) as stream:
            stream.send(b'hello')
            stream.close()
            print('done')
```

**this is the code of the client, maybe I have to change even the server's code or the torrc file?***

Comment: Is it a specific address that doesn't work, or any address? Do both regular websites and onion services both not work?

Comment: Only hidden service doesn't work

Comment: Is it a v2 service or v3?

Comment: It's v3 I think, So that's the problem?

Comment: And if it is how do I create a v2 service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torpy doesn't support v3 onion services. You can find details here: https://github.com/torpyorg/torpy#todo

If you're trying to use torpy to connect to your own onion service, you can make it a v2 service instead, but v2 services are deprecated and [will be removed](https://blog.torproject.org/v2-deprecation-timeline) from the network later this year. If you want to make a v2 service anyways, you can use the `HiddenServiceVersion 2` line in your torrc when creating a new service.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try

Comment: Nop, the error is always the same :(

Comment: Did you delete your old hidden service directory and let Tor create a new one? And you'll need to add a lot more details about what you're doing, what steps you've taken, and the actual address you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Ok, so...i deleted the old dir and recreated, I'm trying to use tor such as a proxy to access to a TCP server to connect two devices.

Comment: The steps i've done are quite standard. I've opened the torrc file, removed the  '#' and it look like this:

Comment: ''' HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
HiddenServiceVersion 2 '''

Comment: Oh the url is 'http://53bh24wmwt2mxrhh.onion'

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not able to reach that address even in Tor Browser. It sounds like you're doing things correctly, but Stack Exchange isn't really good for debugging these types of things. If you can get a v2 address that works in the browser but not torpy, I would file a bug with torpy since I would expect your example code to work with a v2 address.

Comment: I used my Own python script to start the Tor server and it worked. So I think Apache was the problema. Thanks for your help. Ah the oink was not reach able coz I've stopper the server. In my place is 00.00